# Nested for loop doesn't work in python while reading a same csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, nested-loops

I'm a beginner in python, and tried to find solution by googling. However, I couldn't find any solution that I wanted.

What I'm trying to do with python is pre-processing of data that finds keywords and get all rows that include keyword from a large csv file.

And somehow the nested loop goes through `just once` and then it doesn't go through on `second loop`.

The code shown below is a part of my code that finds keywords from the `csv` file and writes into text file.

```
def main():
   #Calling file (Directory should be changed)
   data_file = 'dataset.json'
   #Loading data.json file
   with open(data_file, 'r') as fp:
       data = json.load(fp)

       #Make the list for keys    
       key_list = list(data.keys())
       #print(key_list)
   preprocess_txt = open("test_11.txt", "w+", -1, "utf-8")
   support_fact = 0

   for i, k in enumerate(key_list):
       count = 1
       #read csv, and split on "," the line  
       with open("my_csvfile.csv", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as csvfile:
           reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
           #The number of q_id is 2
           #This is the part that the nested for loop doesn't work!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
           if len(data[k]['Qids']) == 2:
               print("Number 2")
               for m in range(len(data[k]['Qids'])):
                   print(len(data[k]['Qids']))
                   q_id = [data[k]['Qids'][m]]
                   print(q_id)
                   for row in reader: #--->This nested for loop doesn't work after going through one loop!!!!!
                       if all([x in row for x in q_id]):
                           print("YES!!!")
                           preprocess_txt.write("%d %s %s %s\n" % (count, row[0], row[1], row[2]))
                               count += 1
```

For the details of above code,

First, it extracts all keys from `data.json` file, and then put those keys into list(`key_list`).

Second, I used `all([x in row for x in q_id])` method to check each row which contains a keyword(`q_id`).

However, as I commented above in the code, when the length of `data[k]['Qids']` has 2, it prints out `YES!!!` at first loop correctly, but doesn't print out `YES!!!`at second loop which means it doesn't go into `for row in reader` loop even though that csv file contains the keyword.

The figure of print is shown as below,

[image: The output of for loop]

What did I do wrong..? or what should I add for the code to make it work..?

Can anybody help me out..?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Why open the file multiple times? Open it once and then do whatever you want with the data. @paulc1111

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For sake of example, let's say I have a CSV file which looks like this:

**foods.csv**

```
beef,stew,apple,sauce
apple,pie,potato,salami
tomato,cherry,pie,bacon
```

And the following code, which is meant to simulate the structure of your current code:

```
def main():
    import csv

    keywords = ["apple", "pie"]

    with open("foods.csv", "r") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)

        for keyword in keywords:
            for row in reader:
                if keyword in row:
                    print(f"{keyword} was in {row}")

        print("Done")

main()
```

The desired result is that, for every keyword in my list of keywords, if that keyword exists in one of the lines in my CSV file, I will print a string to the screen - indicating in which row the keyword has occurred.

However, here is the actual output:

```
apple was in ['beef', 'stew', 'apple', 'sauce']
apple was in ['apple', 'pie', 'potato', 'salami']
Done
>>>
```

It was able to find both instances of the keyword `apple` in the file, but it didn't find `pie`! So, what gives?

**The problem**

The `file` handle (in your case `csvfile`) yields its contents once, and then they are consumed. Our `reader` object wraps around the file-handle and consumes its contents until they are exhausted, at which point there will be no rows left to read from the file (the internal file pointer has advanced to the end), and the inner for-loop will not execute a second time.

**The solution**

Either move the interal file pointer to the beginning using `seek` after each iteration of the outer for-loop, or read the contents of the file once into a list or similar collection, and then iterate over the list instead:

Updated code:

```
def main():
    import csv

    keywords = ["apple", "pie"]

    with open("foods.csv", "r") as file:
        contents = list(csv.reader(file))

        for keyword in keywords:
            for row in contents:
                if keyword in row:
                    print(f"{keyword} was in {row}")

        print("Done")

main()
```

New output:

```
apple was in ['beef', 'stew', 'apple', 'sauce']
apple was in ['apple', 'pie', 'potato', 'salami']
pie was in ['apple', 'pie', 'potato', 'salami']
pie was in ['tomato', 'cherry', 'pie', 'bacon']
Done
>>>
```

Comment: Oh... That's why....! I might keep in mind when I do those stuffs!!! :DD Thanks for the explanation with the example! :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your **reader** variable contains only the first line of your csv file, thus `for row in reader` executes only once.

try:

```
with open("my_csvfile.csv", newline='', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as csvfile:
```

`newline=''` is the new argument introduced above.

reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3

Quote: "If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''`